# htaccess rewrite URL from subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to set up a rewrite rule in our htaccess. We have a search component that directs to the URL:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/component/search?searchword=word&searchphrase=all&start=10
```

We'd like to show it as:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/search/word/10
```

I've been trying this with no avail so far, this is what I have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /component/search/?searchword=$1&searchphrase=all&start=$2 [L]
```

Is there something missing?  Could other rules be interfering with it?

Answer (score 0):

At least you should escape the slashes and the question mark

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /component\/search\/\?searchword=$1\&searchphrase=all\&start=$2$ [L]
```

And you should not put ampersands (&) in your query string - use %26 or & instead...

Answer (score 0):

You generate your link in the first place as

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/search/word/10
```

and use .htaccess such as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  /component/search/search.php?searchword=$1&searchphrase=all&start=$2  [L]
```

to rewrite it to the dynamic form your search.php script can handle. Your attempt basically looks OK (except that you need search.php, not search), so you might want to check if "mod rewrite" is enabled on your server. You might have to wrap the above code in

```
<IfModule "mod_rewrite.c">
RewriteEngine...
</IfModule>
```

Consult with your hosting service.